# Programmatically Upload Files from Client to IIS

Tags: iis-6, upload

How would I set up IIS to allow clients to programmatically upload files to a folder on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You would need some app in IIS to receive the byte stream. You can use web services for this type of file transfer. Then it would be up to your service layer to save them in the desiered location. Also you would need it to set that folder to have write access and most likely be working in Full Trust mode. You could check out this app and see how he's doing it in Silverlight from an asp.net page. http://www.michielpost.nl/Silverlight/MultiFileUploader/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write code to accomplish this for you.
Tim gave an example for a .NET page.

If you are in shared hosting, your hosting provider may provide COM+ components you could call from ASP pages such as AspUpload or SaFileUp